# wpdb->insert and stripslashes against sql injection

Tags: wpdb

I've been reading the codex at this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep

The code i wrote before reading that page is this:

```
$data   = array(
    'col1' => $v['float'],
    'col2' => stripslashes($v['string'])
);
$format = array( '%f', '%s' );
$wpdb->insert( 'table', $data, $format );
```

Basically i manually pass stripslashed values in the $data array. Now, is this code correct and secure or shall i perform a `$_REQUEST = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST );`? Is there any important difference or is it the same?

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1269) for the `$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format)` method you will find this comment:

> Data to insert (in column => value pairs). Both $data columns and
>   $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL escaped).

so you shouldn't need to do the SQL escape yourself on the data.

As far as I understand the process, the data inserted into the `$wpdb->insert()` method, goes through:

- the `$wpdb->prepare()` method,
- which uses `$wpdb->escape_by_ref()`,
- which uses `$wpdb->_real_escape()`, for non floating values: `! is_float( $string )`,
- that uses the PHP wrapper `mysql_real_escape_string()` or  `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for WP 3.9+ with PHP 5.5+.

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function:

> Escapes special characters in the unescaped_string, taking into
>   account the current character set of the connection so that it is safe
>   to place it in a mysql_query(). If binary data is to be inserted, this
>   function must be used.
>        mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following
>   characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.
>        This function must always (with few exceptions) be used to make data safe before sending a query to MySQL.

But as stated in the Codex page you refer to, in older versions of PHP the `addslashes` can be automatically applied to the `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` globals. The [Magic Quotes feature](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and removed in 5.4.

Comment: so, at the end, what should i do? what's the correct and safe way to pass a string to `wpdb->insert`? if i don't stripslash the string, i don't think i will be able to preserve an eventual new line in a textarea...right?

Comment: This should take care of SQL injections, but you still have to do the validation/sanitazion. I think new lines will be preserved. If you want to allow HTML input, consider using `wp_kses()` to strip out evil scripts.

Comment: no html, only \n new lines...so i don't have to worry about evil scripts...

Comment: I'm not sure you want to strip out all HTML or just encode it. If you want to strip HTML and only allow alphanumerics and white spaces (including new lines): `echo preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/i', '', wp_strip_all_tags( $text, FALSE ) );` but this might be too restrict for you ?
There also exsits the WordPress functions [`esc_html()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html) to escape HTML blocks and
[`esc_textarea()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_textarea) to escape the textarea content.

Comment: To strip out any `%` encoded octets: `$text = preg_replace( '|%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]|', '', $text );` I'm not sure this exists as a special function, but  it's included in some WordPress functions.

Comment: Was this question still unsolved?